# Can you wear a magic spell component?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, warlock, spell-components

To cast a "Hex" spell (Player's Handbook, pg. 251, Warlock 1 lvl spell), you must use an arcane focus or a component called "petrified eye of a newt". I thought it was very cool to wear the last one around my neck like a necklace, but can I actually wear the magical component?

Comment: If it's a component, won't it be consumed?

Comment: @JoãoMendes: No, in 5e the default is that it's not consumed.  A few spells specifically say the component is consumed, usually ones where there's a cost in GP associated, like the diamond dust for Greater Restoration, or some but not all of the components for Legend Lore.

Comment: Ah, I see. Ok, baggage from previous editions, clearly. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Yes; you also have to use a free hand

This is covered under the rules on [material components](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#MaterialM), on p. 203 of the *PHB*:

> Casting some spells requires particular objects,
> specified in parentheses in the component entry. [...]
> A spellcaster must have a hand free to access these
> components, but it can be the same hand that he or she
> uses to perform somatic components

So you could wear it around your neck on a string, as long as you have a free hand to manipulate it when you cast the spell.

Answer (score 5):

#### Nothing in the rules prevents it.

The [rules on material components](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#MaterialM), among other details, say (PHB, page 203):

> A spellcaster must have a hand free to access these
> components, but it can be the same hand that he or she
> uses to perform somatic components.

The sole requirement is that you must use one of your hand to access this component: if you do not have any difficulties in reaching it when you wear it as a necklace, then no rules prevent it.

Anyway, recall that the final decision is up to the DM, even if I fail to see if it may cause any mechanical/balancing issues.